# MATLAB. Setting up bvp4c for second order ode - reaction diffusion equation

Tags: matlab, error-handling, syntax-error, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve for this second order ODE in steady state using bvp4c with the boundary conditions where at x=0, C_L=1 and x=100, C_L=0.

[Image of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/284Pe.png)

```
function bvp4c_test
%Diffusion coefficient
D_ij= 1*10^-6;

%Rate constants
k_1 = 0.00193;
k_2 = 0.00255;
k_3 = 4.09;
d_1 = 0.007;
d_2 = 3.95*10^-5;
d_3 = 2.26;

%Equilibrium constants
K_1 = 3.63;
K_2 = 0.0155;
K_3 = 0.553;
K_4 = 9.01;
%K_5 = 0.077;
%K_6 = 0.000818;
K_i = 0.139;

%Total Receptors
N_T =1.7;

solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,10,11),[0 0]);

sol = bvp4c(@(x,y)odefcn(x,y,D_ij,k_1,k_2,k_3,d_1,d_2,d_3,K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4,K_i,N_T),@twobc,solinit);


plot(sol.x,sol.y(1,:))

function dC_Ldx = odefcn(x,C_L_derivs,D_ij,k_1,k_2,k_3,d_1,d_2,d_3,K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4,K_i,N_T)


C_L = C_L_derivs(1);
dC_Ldx(1) = C_L_derivs(1);

N_r = (-(1+(C_L./K_2))+...
    sqrt(((1+(C_L./K_2)).^2)-4.*((2./K_4).*(1+(C_L./K_2).*(1+(1./K_i).*(1+(C_L./K_3))))).*(-N_T)))./...
    (2.*(2./K_4).*(1+(C_L./K_2).*(1+(1./K_i).*(1+(C_L./K_3)))));

N_R = (C_L./K_1).*N_r;
N_r2 = (1./K_4).*(N_r).^2;
N_rR = (C_L./(2.*K_2.*K_4)).*(N_r).^2;
N_pR = (C_L./(2.*K_2.*K_4.*K_i)).*(N_r).^2;
N_R2 = ((C_L.^2)./(K_2.*K_3.*K_4.*K_i)).*(N_r).^2;

R_L = ((2.*d_1.*(N_T-N_r-N_r2-N_rR-N_pR-N_R2))-(2.*k_1.*C_L.*N_r))+...
    ((2.*d_2.*(N_T-N_r-N_R-N_r2-N_pR-N_R2)))-((k_2.*C_L.*(N_T-N_r-N_R-N_rR-N_pR-N_R2)))+...
    (d_3.*(N_T-N_r-N_R-N_r2-N_rR-N_pR))-(2.*k_3.*C_L.*(N_T-N_r-N_R-N_r2-N_rR-N_R2));


dC_Ldx(2) = -R_L./D_ij;
end

function res = twobc(ya,yb)
res = [ ya(1)-1; yb(1) ];
end
end
```

After running the code the get the following error messages:

```
Error using bvp4c (line 251)
Unable to solve the collocation equations -- a singular Jacobian encountered.

Error in bvp4c_test (line 30)
sol = bvp4c(@(x,y)odefcn(x,y,D_ij,k_1,k_2,k_3,d_1,d_2,d_3,K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4,K_i,N_T),@twobc,solinit);
```

Am I setting up my code correctly? Did I write the second order differential equation correctly?

I'm still very new to MATLAB and would appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!